# Want to display black color keyboard in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I just bought the new iPad and found the amazing looking keyboard which pops up while asking for passcode.

I would like to have the same black colored keyboard through out my iPad Applications which i am currently working on.

Can any1 help me figure it out how to achieve this programatically , i know that apple provides only 2 types  of keyboard looks. But still fellas lets give it a shot and try it out..  what say.. so any help would be appreciated .

thanks  in advance !!

NOTE: P.S. i am not talking about any jailbroken or any such stuff. I want to achieve this through coding in Xcode using my mac.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've used this in iPhone but you can try this to iPad. Try to set `keyboardAppearance` property of the text field to `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert`. This gives a black background.

Comment: yes right but by doing this the keyboard appears with less opacity and  
looks more transparent .. I have lots of elements when a keyboard pops us, so can't afford to have a semi transparent keyboard..
Appriciate your answer thought but i need the keyboard style which is there in the iPad where we type the passcode !!

Comment: This sounds almost there to me - you could listen out for keyboard notifications and display a solid black color view behind it, perhaps?

Comment: With XCode 4.5 and iOS 6, I don't find that this changes the color of the keyboard on iPad. Just the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in API for this. You would have to build a custom keyboard to get that exact look. As suggested by others, `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert` comes close.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert.